# Ignore given custom value Jackson JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

If I have a property with a value set to "custom_string", is there a way to ignore it when using a POJO and Jackson?

I know you can ignore null using `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`, but is there a way to ignore a custom value? I can't seem to find any notes on this anywhere.

I know it's possible to just `return value.equals("custom_string") ? null : value` in my Getter... but I'd prefer a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is *the smartest* differs by your requirement.

Jackson provides the way to ignore the property with default value (by annotating class with `@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)`, so if you could set the field's default value "custom_string", the solution might be available.

Other solutions I know are to convert the object to `Map` and then simply serialize, to add the annotation by reflection, or to create your own custom serializer. The custom serializer may look like this:

```
public class YourItem {
    public String key;
    public String item;
}

public class YourItemSerializer extends StdSerializer<YourItem> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(YourItem value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("key", value.key);
        if (!"custom_string".equals(value.item))
            jgen.writeStringField("item", value.item);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: `@JsonIgnore` can take parameters? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem.  What is the smartest is different by your situation. Jackson provides the way to ignore the property with default value, so if you could set the field's default value "custom_string", the solution might be available. Other solutions I know are to convert the object to `Map`, to add the annotation by reflection, or to create your own `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 8):

One more possible solution is to use custom filter where you could combine more than one requirement. Let's say we want to filter null values and "custom_string", then we should specify that we will use JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM value and provide filter implementation. Example:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = StringFilter.class)
private String name;

// Custom filter that will omit null and "custom_string" values.
public class StringFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null) {
            // Filter null's.
            return true;
        }

        // Filter "custom_string".
        return "custom_string".equals(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me. I want to filter few fields in response based for some flag. I have a class which returns true/false based on the flag in yml file. But this class is not getting autowired in filter class. It is coming as null. My filter class is similar to StringFilter class

Answer (score 4):

Tried using `JsonInclude.Include.Custom` and it worked like a charm.

The annotation:

```
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = MaskingFilter.class)
    private String firstname;
```

The filter class:

```
    public class MaskingFilter {
      public MaskingFilter() {
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object value) {
        if(value == null)
            return true;
        return "****MASKED_VALUE****".equals(value);
      }
  }
```

if firstname in this case, equals "****MASKED_VALUE****" it is not a part of the result.