# Hide negative values from a json by jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, floating-point

I am developing a REST API. In one of my endpoints, my model (pojo) looks like this:

```
public class Tax{
    String name;
    Float value;
}
```

Anyway, I want to hide the field 'value' in my JSON response, if it's negative (-1 in my case). Is there any jackson annotation for this purpose
or any other workaround?

Comment: Is this what you need?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31250751/4636715

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the most sensible answer.

- add @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT). 
  import this -> `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;`
- make the default value of that attribute to -1.

  ```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)

  public class Tax{ 
      String name; 
      Float value = -1; 
  }
  ```