# How to exclude a Null List in a JSON object while Parsing to POJO

Tags: java, json, rest, parsing

I have A JSON Response which is having some Object and Objects have some List of values.

```
"A": {
  "Object1": {
     "list":[
         null,
         null,
         null
       ]
   }
   "Object2": {
     "list":[
         null,
         null,
         null
       ]
   }
   "Object3": {
     "list":[
         2,
         3,
         8
       ]
   }
 }
```

I want to exclude the Complete Object "Object1" and "Object2" if the list is having null values.

I tried

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

both at class level and field level but still its not excluding.

Comment: Try this answer from a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54644173/2947378

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonSetter` annotation on the field with specification, how nulls should be handled:

```
@JsonSetter(nulls=Nulls.AS_EMPTY) // null will clear to empty list
public List<String> names = Collections.emptyList();
```

(you need at Jackson in version at least 2.9)